# loading button while download file is not starting

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, phpexcel

I want my user to download a PHPExcel file and I want my button to disable and say Loading... while the file is not starting to download. The thing is the download button is getting data from my database MySql to put in every cell of the Excel format required to generate this file. I cant find some answer to this type pf problem. Thanks in advance.

This is my PHP code to generate the Excel file.

```
    if(isset($_POST['dl_xls'])){
    include_once('php/connection.php');
    include('Classes/PHPExcel.php');
    require_once "Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";

    //auto generate PR number >>>

        $sql_check_exist = "SELECT pr_digits_ID FROM pr_digits WHERE PR_ID ='".$pr_id."' LIMIT 1";
        $query_check_exist = mysqli_query($db,$sql_check_exist);
        $sql_max_digits = "SELECT MAX(pr_digit) AS max_digit FROM pr_digits WHERE year ='".$year."' AND month = '".$month."' ORDER BY pr_digits_ID DESC LIMIT 20";
        $query_max_digits = mysqli_query($db,$sql_max_digits);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_check_exist) == 0){

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_max_digits)>0){

                $r_d = mysqli_fetch_array($query_max_digits);
                $max_digit = $r_d['max_digit'];
                $max_digit += 1;
                $sql_add_digit= "INSERT INTO pr_digits (PR_ID, year, month, pr_digit) VALUES ('".$pr_id."','".$year."', '".$month."', '".$max_digit."')";
                mysqli_query($db,$sql_add_digit);
                $dig = sprintf('%03d',$max_digit);
                $c = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$dig;

            }else{

                $r_d = mysqli_fetch_array($query_max_digits);
                $max_digit = 1;
                $sql_add_digit = "INSERT INTO pr_digits (PR_ID, year, month, pr_digit) VALUES ('".$pr_id."','".$year."', '".$month."', '".$max_digit."')";
                mysqli_query($db,$sql_add_digit);
                $dig = sprintf('%03d',$max_digit);
                $c = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$dig;

            }
        }else{

        }



    //<<<<<


    $col_no = 17;   
    //load template
    $obj_tmp = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("src/dole_template.xls");
    $obj_tmp ->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    while($data_row=mysqli_fetch_array($rsitems)){

        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('A'.$col_no, $data_row['quantity']);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('B'.$col_no, $data_row['unit_issue']);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('C'.$col_no, $data_row['item_des']);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('G'.$col_no, $data_row['unit_cost']);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('H'.$col_no, $data_row['total_cost']);
    $col_no = $col_no + 2;  
    }


        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('B7', $for_use);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('A12', $f_office);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('D12', $c);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('G12', $pr_date);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('B41', $pr_purpose);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('G41', $pr_brand);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E43', $pr_reason);
        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('B47', $pr_year);

            ### Recommending Approval
            if($f_office === 'IMSD/PROPERTY' || $f_office === 'IMSD/PERSONNEL' || $f_office === 'IMSD/CASHIER' || $f_office === 'IMSD/DOCKET' || $f_office === 'OD' || $f_office === 'ARD/ADMIN'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'JULIE F. RODRIGUEZ');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'OIC-Chief, IMSD');

            }else if($f_office === 'EPWW' || $f_office === 'EPWW/LIVELIHOOD'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'AURORA E. HALCON');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'OIC, TSSD-EPWW');

            }else if($f_office === 'LRLS' || $f_office === 'LRLS/PLANNING'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'NELIA MUNGCAL');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'OIC, TSSD-LRLS');

            }else if($f_office === 'MALSU'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'ATTY. MARION SEVILLA');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Head, MALSU');

            }else if($f_office === 'COA'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'MILAGROS PILAR');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Audit Team Leader');

            }else if($f_office === 'ARD/LABOR'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'ATTY. MARIA CONSUELO S. BACAY');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Asst. Regional Director');

            }else if($f_office === 'MPFO'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'ROWELLA G. GRANDE');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Director II, MPFO');

            }else if($f_office === 'CFO'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'ANDREA P. CABANSAG');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Director II, CFO');

            }else if($f_office === 'MFO'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'LEONIDES CASTILLON JR.');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Director II, MFO');

            }else if($f_office === 'PFO'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'MA. CORAZON PEPITO');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Director II, PFO');

            }else if($f_office === 'MTPLFO'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'BENVENUTO C. ALEGRE');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Director II, MTPLFO');

            }else if($f_office === 'QCFO'){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E49', 'LILIBETH CAGARA');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E50', 'Director II, QCFO');

            }

            ### Approved
            if($total_s > 50000){

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E54', 'NELSON C. HORNILLA');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E55', 'OIC, Regional Director');
            }else{

                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E54', 'IRMA S. VALIENTE');
                $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('E55', 'Assistant Regional Director');
            }



        $obj_tmp -> getActiveSheet() -> SetCellValue('H39', $total_s);

    $filename= $c.'.xls';
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $obj_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($obj_tmp, 'Excel5');
    $obj_writer ->save('php://output');

    $update_pr_no = "UPDATE pr_table SET save = 1, pr_no='".$c."'  WHERE PR_ID = '".$pr_id."'";
        mysqli_query($db,$update_pr_no);
        mysqli_close($db);
```

I know I need to use some jquery here to get that logic but I dont know how XD I got  some simple jquery that changes the text inside the button.

```
    function button_ds() {
        _('add_btn').disabled = true;
        _('dl_xls').innerHTML = 'Click to go Back';

    }
```

And the HTML form that POST the dl_xls

```
    <form method="POST" role="form" id="dl_xls_frm">
                            <button type="submit" name="dl_xls" id="dl_xls" class="btn btn-success" onclick="button_ds()">Download Excel  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                            </form>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean by "The thing is the download button is getting data from my database MySql to put in every cell of the Excel format required to generate this file"? Also what is you add_btn?

Comment: the add_btn is for mysql table items. So when click I the download btn which is dl_xls the add btn will disabled so they cant add another data to my table while downloading or downloading is not starting

Comment: I mean by the thing is.. The dl_xls button is for download at the same time it will run some SQL to get data from my database then put every single of those data to every specific column in my EXCEL file.